# How do I programmatically save an NSDocument?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, macos-sierra, nsdocument

I need to programmatically save the active document of an NSDocument based app from within a method of the NSViewController that controls the document view.  Menu items do this by sending save() to the first responder.  What is the best way to do this programmatically?  Should I A) get a reference to the NSDocument (somehow) and then call the save method or B) send a save: message to the first responder?

Comment: It depends on why and from where you want to save.

Comment: From an NSViewController - I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: Are you just trying to trigger an autosave or do want to create a new Version (you know, triggered when the _user_ uses the Save command)?

Comment: I want a new version - just like when the user selects File->Save from the menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say (B) is the easiest to do. All you have to do is call this line from any `NSResponder` down the chain (like your view controller):

```
NSApp.sendAction(#selector(NSDocument.save(_:)), to: nil, from: self)
```

This will have exactly the same effect as choosing "Save" from the menu bar.